# Color of selected rows in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to change color of selected rows in QTableWidget using python.
http://postimg.org/image/iyxb0wm4r/
I want that green part to be red.

If i try:

```
table = self.my_table
palette = QtGui.QPalette(table.palette())
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, Qt.red)
table.setPalette(palette)
```

it producies next picture. I need to double click, so the selected text is red.

http://postimg.org/image/rtc06mlil/

If I try:

```
  table = self.my_table
  table.setAutoFillBackground(True)
  p = table.palette()
  p.setColor(table.backgroundRole(), Qt.red)
  table.setPalette(p)
```

it does this: (I can't post images and I can post only two links!) I try to put the link in comment. Anyway, it just set the color of grid to red.

Comment: http://s4.postimg.org/w8c1nrpx9/red_grid.png last link.

Answer (score 2):

So I found solution.

```
p = QtGui.QPalette(table.palette())
#This two for setting text color
p.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText,
            QtGui.QBrush(QColor("red")))
p.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText,
            QtGui.QBrush(QColor("red")))

#this two for setting background color
p.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Highlight,
            QtGui.QBrush(QColor(255,0,0,127)))
p.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Highlight,
            QtGui.QBrush(QColor("255,0,0,127")))
```

One thing - works bit differently on Linux and Windows, but for my purposes it is more than suitable.